# Reversing 'groupby' aggregation operations

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have a sequence of positive integers $(x_i )_{i=1}^n$ with associated 'categories' $(c_i)_{i=1}^n$, where $c_i \in \{C_1, \dots, C_m\}$, $m < n$. For each category $C_j$ we can consider the aggregations $X_j = \sum_i \delta_{c_i = C_j} x_i$. For example we might have that $x_i$ is the annual income for a given household, and $c_i$ is the city that household is in so that $X_j$ is the total income for all households in a city.

Suppose now that we are only given $(x_i )_{i=1}^n$, $(X_j)_{j=1}^m$ and we are tasked with inferring $(c_i)_{i=1}^n$. One can of course brute-force all possible assignments, but the solutions may not be unique and brute-forcing is very inefficient. Is there any literature that considers these kinds of problems, and what tools are available to tackle these questions?

Comment: Sounds like The Subset Sum Problem, q.v., which is, given a bunch of (positive) numbers, and a target number, to find a subset of the numbers that sums to the target (or to prove there is no such subset. I believe the problem is NP-complete, which in practical terms means no one knows an efficient algorithm, and many are convinced that there is no efficient algorithm.

Comment: just as an intuition check, if you group by max or count (as are both standard in database operations) rather than sum then backsolving is going to be impossible

Comment: @hunter I agree, but for the case of summation there is more hope e.g. if x_i = 2^i then you can recover the categories by looking at the ith bit. This is an extreme example but demonstrates the heuristic that if x_i, x_j can be considered independently if they have a very different scale.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for the lead. Even if no efficient solution is possible my problem space may be small enough that a sufficiently optimized inefficient algorithm is enough.